# playonlinux is unable to find 32bits / 64bits OpenGL library

Tags: 12.04, games, opengl, playonlinux

When I open a fresh instalation of playonlinux, it gives 2 dialog box as mentioned in title:

> playonlinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL library
>   
> playonlinux is unable to find 64bits OpenGL library

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (**and new to it**) and would like to know how to solve this problem

**EDIT** TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
~$ playonlinux
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.1.8) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: 
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: 
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: Capture...
[maj_check] Message: Web version : 1349866727
[maj_check] Message: Current local version : 1349563245
[maj_check] Message: Updating list
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/startup_after_server: line 38: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/startup_after_server: line 38: [: : integer expression expected
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: LAST_TIMESTAMP 1349866727
```

**EDIT Nvidea print screens**
[image]

What it says:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your hardware specs and which video driver you are using.

Comment: @Anthony as I said I am new to ubuntu. If you tell me how to find a dump for you I will put that up. Besides that. Mine is a lenova ideapad U410 i7 3rd gen laptop. http://www.laptopmag.com/review/laptops/lenovo-ideapad-u410.aspx

Comment: Please launch playonlinux from the command line and report the output in your question. Open a terminal and type "playonlinux". I suspect there is a driver issue. Whether you should be using the nvidia hardware or the intel HD4000 we will see.

Comment: @Anthony I have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound strange, but here is how I got it working! This is not a real answer

I unistalled ubuntu ( I was on 12.04 ) and I installed the new Ubuntu 12.10 ... I then installed `wine` first and then `playonlinux` , both from the ubuntu software center. It worked like a charm :)

Thanks for all your help in answering this, but I still havent figured out whats wrong with that as its working now and I am not in a mood to crash my `playonlinux` to solve it!

Comment: No need to reinstall Ubuntu or `playonlinux` in whatever order. The trick is to just install `wine`, because it depends on `libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1` for both amd64 and i386 architectures. That works for in-kernel-tree graphics drivers as well as proprietary ones.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a tentative answer, a revision or additional information may be needed.**

Find the pci BusID of your nvidia gpu. Open a terminal and type `lscpi |grep VGA`:

```
anthony@terminal:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] (rev a1)
```

Edit your xorg.conf file to load the nvidia driver. Open a terminal and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Add to that file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 430"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"                   # Use lspci | grep VGA to find BusID
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection
```

Edit the above example to include your hardware specific information. A reboot is needed after the alteration. This should be enough to get the nvidia driver loaded. Additional configuration may be performed by typing `sudo nvidia-settings` in the terminal.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5Ejy4vzb here is the log file. But still the error dialog boxes come. I followed your steps to add the text. I added it to the end of the file.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you install the nvidia driver. The nvidia hardware you have is slightly better than the intel hd4000 anyway. Follow this guide here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia You can also install it through synaptic package manager. Once the install is complete, you should be all set up. Let me know once you are finished and I will help you with additional configurations as needed.

Comment: Hi nvidea is already installed and when I open it from dash board it says nvidea is not being used and in-order to use it just enter nvidea-xconfig as root. I did that. But my resolution got weird. It wouldnt go beyond 640x480. And I tried MANY solutions on the internet and put in the exact resolution of my monitor. I had to reinstall ubuntu

Comment: The "need" to reinstall nvidia aside, how was it installed in the first place? From Additional Drivers, or from nvidia directly? Second, although using nvidia-xconfig can be useful, it is my experience that it is not always 100%.

Comment: I didnot install it explicitly from any-source. My best guess is that: I am connected to the internet while installing ubuntu, and I did check the options to update-ubuntu and install required 3rd party drivers (in the installer first screen)

Comment: so you have reinstalled ubuntu? And the nvidia driver is currently installed?

Comment: yes, but still the error persists when I open playonlinux

Comment: I have attached screenshots of the dialog box for nvidea driver

Comment: `locate libGL.so`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i repaired with those :

Remove all parts of playonlinux and wine .

setup  [wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)(first) and [Playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.1.8/PlayOnLinux_4.1.8.deb) . after update your nvidia drivers on [nvidia driver page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-304.51-driver.html)  (only download and setup it )

That's it :)

Comment: Nope, it actually crashed my system to a 640x480 screen and I had to restore the system

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your proprietary drivers for your Nvidia. Go to "System Settings > Additional Drivers" and install the one who's not "post-release".

I found one solution on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035365) in a Wine/PlayOnLinux thread :

> "Okay, so I repeatedly purged and installed POL, eventually deciding to delete the file "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list" (although I am pretty sure the word old was in there somewhere) as I was getting errors when using "apt-get update" to do with this file. This seems to have rectified the problem with the request for 32- and 64-bits OpenGL libraries."

I think you're having the same problem, so try this solution.

Comment: I tries this, didnt sove the problem